# Xmlgregoriancalendar not allowed leading zero in ddMMyyyy

Tags: java, date, leading-zero, xmlgregoriancalendar

I tried to get `XMLGregorianCalendar` with date format `ddMMyyy`. When I tried to convert it from `Date`, it kept throwing me:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Leading zeros are not allowed.

Is there anyway to fix it?

Thanks!

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
XMLGregorianCalendar gTest = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(format.format(new Date(1, 9, 2018)));
```

Comment: What do you need an `XMLGregorianCalendar` with format `ddMMyyyy` for? I’m tempted to ask “What makes you think that you need…?” because such a thing cannot exist. Please give us the bigger picture, because I’m sure that a good way exists, maybe even a much better way.

Comment: I need to pass an XMLGregorianCalendar object with ddMMyyy format based on the given Interface Data Mapping. Somehow I encountered this issue while performing testing. But seems like, it is not achievable by doing this, so might change the format of passing it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I get an `XMLGregorianCalendar` with year 10041907 and no other fields defined. It’s not what you expected, that’s not that hard to see, but I see no exception.

Comment: Hmm... sorry that I didn't provide more info. What I tried is to pass a date with a Day is less than 10 , meaning that from 1 to 9, which will produced a 01082018 (ddMMyyyy) format based on my post. And it hit the leading zero issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn’t use the `Date` class if you can avoid it. You may also want to avoid `XMLGregorianCalendar`. `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are long outdated, and the latter in particular renowned for being troublesome. Today we have so much better in `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It may also sometimes replace `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

But taking your word for it, you’ve got an old-fashioned `Date` object — maybe from a legacy API that you cannot change or don’t want to change just now. You need to convert it to an `XMLGregorianCalendar`. I still prefer to use `java.time` for the conversion.

```
    Date oldfashionedDate = // some Date equal to 1 August 2018 at 00:00 in my time zone;
    LocalDate modernDate = oldfashionedDate.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .toLocalDate();
    XMLGregorianCalendar gTest = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
            .newXMLGregorianCalendar(modernDate.toString());
    System.out.println(gTest);
```

This prints:

> 2018-08-01

You asked for format `ddMMyyyy`. You cannot have that. Or more precisely, the only way you can have that is in a string, not in an `XMLGregorianCalendar`. `XMLGregorianCalendar.toString()` produces XML format, and this is defined in the XML Schema (see the link at the bottom). It goes like for example `2018-08-01`, `2018-08-01T00:00:00` or `2018-08-01T00:00:00+02:00`.

### What went wrong in your code?

I could not reproduce your `IllegalArgumentException`. On my Java 10 the leading 0 of `01082018` was accepted (on Java 8 too). However, the data type factory parsed the string into a year of 1082018 (more than a million years from now), and since the string ended there, it didn’t parse any month or day of month. So the resulting `XMLGregorianCalendar` had only a year in it, no other fields were defined.

`newXMLGregorianCalendar(String)` accepts only XML format. Apparently a year alone is accepted. The format still follows the specification linked to at the bottom of this answer.

Accepting the leading 0 is probably a bug, though, since the leading zero is not printed back from the `toXMLFormat` method, which was supposed to give the same string back as was parsed, according to the documentation of `newXMLGregorianCalendar(String)`.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition: Lexical representation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#date-lexical-representation)
- [Documentation of `DatatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#newXMLGregorianCalendar-java.lang.String-)